# Is flattening JavaScript 2D arrays worth any performance gain?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array

As far as I know, there are two main ways of storing 2D data. One, a 2D array:

```
var array = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];

// access element at (1, 1)
array[1][1];
```

The other, a flat array with a stored `width`:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var width = 3;

// access element at (1, 1)
array[1 * width + 1];
```

It's being said all over the Internet that "multidimensional" arrays are bad and perform super poorly compared to flat arrays and storing the width. (Also, typed arrays can be used to speed up the second variant even more). However, I really dislike the syntax you must use to access a point with the flat array, and I think that you should code as close to what you mean. Also, it's a lot of (I think) unnecessary math every frame.

I'm in a situation where I need to handle large 2D arrays quickly (you guessed it, a game) and I want to know if flattening my arrays is worth the possible performance gain. So, is it?

Comment: Benchmark it and find out. Or, better yet, don't. If you encapsulate the array properly, it should cost you virtually nothing to transition from one method of storage to the other, after the game is done. Then you'll actually be able to produce useful benchmarks instead of synthetic ones.

Comment: @meagar: Because the second version will involve a lot of juggling from one type of coordinate to the other in this scenario (and besides will be a pain to write), will that cancel out the benefits? That's a little hard to benchmark.

Comment: Neither version should involve anything except a function invocation, something like `getData(x, y)` and `setData(x, y, value)`.

Comment: Why start optimizing there? I'd start with basic refactoring first, then algorithms, then memoization, and finally, only if all that fails I would consider changing a logical data structure for the sake of performance.

Comment: Note that you can store the width as a property of the array: `array.width = 3;`.

Comment: @elclanrs: "changing a logical data structure for the sake of performance" -- that's exactly what I'm worried about.

Comment: I understand, but how do you know this is the bottleneck in your case? All I'm saying is that I would go through my checklist before thinking about changing the data structure that makes sense for your program.

Comment: You could take a look at the [ASM Spec](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/), maybe it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1D array may have a performance benefit due to the index look-up times. A 2D+ array will first have to have one index looked up, then in the resulting array yet another and so forth. There is an initial cost each time but it may be microscopic all in all.

If you really want a gain in performance then consider using *Typed Arrays*. These are actual low-level byte arrays and you can use them with 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 32/64 bits float values, signed and unsigned (latter not for float).

If your numbers are of one type then you can use typed arrays. You use them as any other array with index look-up but performance can be many times as these are optimized by the JS engine(s):

```
var array = new Uint8Array(9);  // 9 x bit-width, here 8 = 9 bytes

// write
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 2;
...etc.

// read
var value1 = array[0];
...etc.
```

Comment: I know (a little) about typed arrays, but those would only come in useful after I have decided 2D or 1D. That's where I'm stuck now. Anyway, thanks for the first paragraph. If it's microscopic then I should go with 2d array.

Comment: @rvighne you cannot use 2D with typed arrays as you cannot put an array at an index, but you can overcome that by using x/y math (`pos = widthOf1DArray * y + x`) x being index in 1. dimension, y in second. Here is a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/performance-of-2d-typed-arrays-vs-normal-arrays/7) to show the difference in performance.

Comment: Nice jsperf, but typed array vs not typed isn't really my main concern here.

Comment: @rvighne ah, I misread it to be about performance. Just ignore :)

Comment: Look at [this jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/2d-array-of-numbers). Turns out that the fastest method is a hybrid of a **non-flat 2D array** and a typed array, at least on the latest Chrome and FF.

Comment: @rvighne thanks for testing, but the test has a few flaws: you are setting up the typed arrays wrong (needs to be a byte count or another typed array buffer) and you are using a random() in there which can skew the test due to its cost. The value read is dumped to the window object and the x/y math for the 1D array is doing two muls instead of 1 mul and 1 add, all which can affect the result. Here is an updated test: http://jsperf.com/2d-array-of-numbers/2

Comment: Thanks for the update, I didn't know that random can skew the results. But according to [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Int8Array) (and my tests) you can pass a JS array to the constructor.

Comment: @rvighne yeah, my bad, I mix it with passing an typed array directly versus typedArray.buffer which would end up with different results if of different widths. You are right. But besides from that the rest is ok :) The cost of random() (or similar costly functions) can cause you to sort of "measure" the random function rather than the array read/write as it consume much of the time per iteration and therefor affect the actual time and gives bias to the result (ie. the time of array read/write will falsely show it takes more time than it actually do).

Comment: OK, understand about the random. I was just looking to compare them though.

Answer (score 3):

I think I've found an ideal solution to my own problem! Here is a [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/2d-array-of-numbers/2).

**UPDATE**: The originial benchmark was incorrect and the updated version shows that flat typed arrays perform just slightly better than 2D typed arrays.

2D arrays turned out to be much slower than the flattened version, just as everyone warns. However, if the second level is a Typed Array, then it performs better <strike>than a flat array (even if the flattened one is typed as well)</strike>. *Thanks to @Ken for pointing me to typed arrays.*

This will allow me to code how I think (`array[x][y]`), while also having superior performance.

Comment: Note that the performance differences between the methods depend on the JS engine and hence browser

Answer (score 1):

I created some jsperf tests for 1000x1000 arrays (larger than the OP used in their jsperf), and added methods for returning a single nested array / flat array slice.

```
var arrDim = 1000;


var clArr = new Array(arrDim);
for (var i = 0; i < arrDim; i++) {
    clArr[i] = new Uint8Array(arrDim);
}

clArr.getSlice = function(i) {
    return this[i];
}
clArr.setVal = function(i, j, val) {
    this[i][j] = val;
}
clArr.getVal = function(i, j) {
    return this[i][j];
}


var flArr = new Uint8Array(Math.pow(arrDim, 2));

flArr.getSlice = function(i) {
    var start = i*arrDim;
    return this.slice(start, start + arrDim);
}
flArr.setVal = function(i, j, val) {
    this[i*arrDim + j] = val;
}
flArr.getVal = function(i, j) {
    return this[i*arrDim + j];
}
```

- [jsperf - get values](https://jsperf.com/js-nested-vs-flat-array-retrieve-values)
- [jsperf - set values](https://jsperf.com/js-nested-vs-flat-array-set-values)
- [jsperf - get slice](https://jsperf.com/js-nested-vs-flat-array-slices)

For getting and setting, Chrome 60 has pretty much the same speed for the 2 methods, and in EdgeHTML 15 the nested array is ~ 50% quicker.

**But most importantly, for getting the nested arrays / slicing, the nested array is much, much quicker.**